# How to get properties from parent class

Tags: c#, .net, getproperties

I want to use `GetProperties` to get the properties from the parent class via the child and, despite researching this, have been unsuccessful.

I tried the next without any result:

```
PropertyInfo[] fields = t.GetProperties();
PropertyInfo[] fields1 = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
PropertyInfo[] propNames = t.BaseType.GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Just got it the properties from the child class, but dont get the properties from the parent.

**Classes**

```
public class A: B
{
    public string a1 { get; set; }

    public string a2 { get; set; }

    public string a3 { get; set; }

    public string a4 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public string b1;
}
```

Using this code I am getting `A`'s properties but not the property in `B`.

Does this code work? Do I need to configure something in some place?

Comment: Can you give us a sample of what your example classes look like, i.e. the `child` and its `parent` class?

Comment: This code works as expected for me, I got all base type properties. So what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Dandré Did it. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Alexander. Just trying to get properties (in this case property) set on the parent class --> B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your declaration

```
public class B
{
    public string b1;
}
```

`b1` is a [field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields), not a property. You should either

- Use [`GetFields()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=netframework-4.7.2):

  ```
  FieldInfo[] fields = t.GetFields();
  ```

  which will get the fields (as expected) - note that [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields) says that

  > Generally, you should use fields only for variables that have private or protected accessibility.
- Make `b1` a property, e.g. by adding `{ get; set; }` accessors to it.